# 1 Record as multiple number of records

Tags: sql

If my table as

```
ID  NAME   PHNO
1   xyz    7895632147
2   abc    8795412632
3   def    9587412306
```

I want output as

```
ID    NAME    PHNO
1     xyz      7895632147
1     xyz      7895632147
1     xyz      7895632147
1     xyz      7895632147
1     xyz      7895632147
2     abc     8795412632
2     abc     8795412632
2     abc     8795412632
2     abc     8795412632
2     abc     8795412632
3     def     9587412306
3     def     9587412306
3     def     9587412306
3     def     9587412306
3     def     9587412306
```

I need to execute it any number of times dynamically here I gave 5 times as example.

How can I do it in microsoft sql server management studio ?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: just cross join to a number table

Comment: Hint: Have a recursive CTE that returns 5 rows. CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Why would you want that in SQL though, can't you just retrieve your data and then start repeating it?

Comment: To add to @jarlh 's comment if your MySQL version does not support CTE  you can use a delivered table approach and cross join that with the table `SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 ...) alias CROSS JOIN table ON ...`

Comment: SELECT * from table
GO 5

Comment: Why do the first five have `'abc'` and not `'xyz'`? What's the logic behind that?

Comment: @stickybit I think he just C/P his text and forgot to write xyz on ID 1 instead of abc on both id 1 and 2 - since its an example

Comment: This question was originally MySQL, no? I wonder if it is OP who made MS SQL server.

Comment: @CetinBasoz It says in the question he uses Microsoft SQL server management studio. So i dont guess its a MySQL related quesiton

Comment: @Thomas, check the edits. Originally it was tagged MySQL and SQL only (yes my fault not reading to the last dot maybe - wouldn't waste my time on the harder code)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [recursive CTE](https://www.essentialsql.com/recursive-ctes-explained/) to do this:

```
declare @terminator int = 5;

with recursivecte as (
select ID,name,phno ,1 as n from testtable
union all
select ID,name,phno, n +1 from recursivecte

where N < @terminator
)
select * from recursivecte
```

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, keep a prebuilt table "tally" for such purposes (it might have just 10 records, which you can proliferate with cartesian joins as needed - or you might use one of the system tables):

```
create table tally (i int);
insert into tally (i)
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10);
```

Then all you need is a cross join:

```
select t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.Phno
from myTable t1
cross join (select * from tally limit 5) t
order by t1.Id;
```

Here is an [SQLFiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9bc71e/3)

**This question was originally MySQL!**

With MS SQL server it is much easier:

```
with tally as
(
  select top(5) row_number() over (order by t1.object_id) as N
  from sys.all_columns t1 
  cross join sys.all_columns t2
)
select t1.Id, t1.Name, t1.Phno
from myTable t1
cross join tally
order by t1.Id;
```

And here is [SQLFiddle demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a928d/1)